# Random preset generator C programming

Tags: c, fsm

Beginner here. For engineering school I am learning how to program in C. One of my assignments is to design a finite state machine. Since I am a guitar player I thought I make a guitar pedal simulation in C. 
With switch case statements I have gotten to the point where I can adjust the controls in the simulation. This (fake) pedal has 3 knobs (level, tone, drive) with each 3 positions (low, middle, high) and a footswitch to put the pedal into action.

To spice things up, I want to create a "random" preset generator which should work like this in the "real world": you push a button and the pedal generates a signal output eg. level high, tone middle, drive low. So to speak there are 3^3 possible outcomes when the button is pushed.

How do I create this in C? I can imagine I have to create a table with these outcomes and make a randomizer function to make it work. But is this the way?

*[edit]*
Thanks to the comments and some further digging I have come to understand my initial idea is not a good example for a FSM. However, for the purpose of the exercise this really does not matter. Part of the learning process is to make mistakes. In the reflection part of the assignment I will explain this to the tutor. I created state chart in UML for some clarification. [state chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwZyM.png)

Original question remains: how can I create a random preset generator in C?

Comment: for me the solution is not through a state machine because the buttons do not define overall 'states'. You are in front of a formula having several variables

Comment: If you really wants a state machine you have only 2 states depending on the footswitch, so on and off (if I well understand how it works). Note also the main for a state machine is not outcomes but incomes (e.g. event and guards producing transitions)

Comment: To add to what @bruno said, state machines are about sequences of symbols. If the order of symbols does not matter (you only care *which* symbol is currently active, not which of the symbols was sent first, nor which symbol was sent 20 symbols ago), then a state machine does nothing for you.

Comment: So, if I understand you right, I can't say there is a state called "signal adjusted" before pressing the footswitch and outputting the signal?

Comment: @MrGreenery what are the other states ? if you only have *signal adjusted* and *signal not adjusted* better use a boolean rather than a state machine ^^

Comment: I think I am starting to understand. Adjustment of the knobs does not lead to a change in state. And what if I leave the footswitch out of the pedal? Then the adjustment would lead directly to a new state? 

@bruno other states are "cable input ready" "subsystems initialised" and "signal overdrive"

Comment: @MrGreenery because I cannot guaranty I understand how an electronic guitar works (I did only 'classic' one when young ;-) ) before to think about how to implement just try to draw your state machine to see if is has sense.  If you have a tool to draw easily your machine it is better (may be an UML tool ?)

Comment: @MrGreenery You can say whatever you want, and you can probably shoehorn a state machine in there, but it doesn't help you, it doesn't simplify or clarify the problem. It is redundant and only complicates your approach. You have some state (the current position of the switches) and you apply the corresponding transformations on the current signal. Unless the transformations should depend on the history of previously set switches, a state machine does absolutely nothing for you (and even *if* you wanted something like a decay, you should probably use a proper filter instead).

Comment: an example of a (UML) state machine simulating a 'corded' phone (so an old one, not a cellphone) : https://www.bouml.fr/doc/figs/state2.png the states and the transitions have sense

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

As to the original question that remains,

The C standard header file `stdlib.h` provides a function defined as `int rand(void);` which produces a pseudo-random integer between the ranges of `0` and `RAND_MAX` inclusive, where `RAND_MAX` is a macro defined as some rather large integer constant (most likely the largest positive value a signed `int` can hold)

In order to ensure that every run of your program has a unique set of values produced by the `rand()` function, you must seed the number generator using the function `void srand(unsigned int);`, which is also provided by `stdlib.h`. Provide this function with a unique value at each runtime, and the random number generator should behave differently on each run.

A common way to seed the pseudo-random number generator is to pass it the result of `time(NULL)` (after including `time.h`), as this function returns the implementation's best approximation as to the current time in the form of a `time_t` which is some implementation defined type for storing the current time.

so short answer to your question:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
  int a, b, c;
  srand( (unsigned int) time(NULL) );
  a = rand() % 3;
  b = rand() % 3;
  c = rand() % 3;
...
```

It may be worth noting that while `rand() % a`, where `a` is some integer greater than zero and less than `RAND_MAX`, should always return an integer between zero and `a-1` inclusive, this result is only truly evenly distributed between zero and `a-1` when `RAND_MAX` is divisible by `a`, but in your case, with an `a` as low as 3, this should not make a significant difference.